# Contrast in contrasts in emmeans

Tags: r, regression, emmeans

I'd like to test if two two contrasts are themselves significantly different.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(emmeans)

data(mtcars)

lm1 <- lm(
  mpg ~ factor(vs) * factor(am),
  data = mtcars
  )

lm1 %>% 
  emmeans(
    pairwise ~ vs | am
  )
```

returns the difference in `mpg` for each value of `vs`

```
$contrasts
am = 0:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 1       -5.69 1.65 28 -3.448  0.0018 

am = 1:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 1       -8.62 1.93 28 -4.464  0.0001
```

...I want to see if these differences are themselves different to each other

Comment: The difference of contrasts is also a contrast.

Comment: Does the answer have to use `emmeans`? You might try this with `multcomp::glht`, which lets you define your own custom linear combination of parameters to test ...

Comment: Take out the `pairwise` part and add `%>% contrast(`interaction = “pairwise”, by = NULL)`

Comment: Following up on @BenBolker — you don’t need any package with this particular example. If you use `contrTrsatment` contrasts (the default), the regression coefficients for the interaction is already the difference of differences.